# How to add more strings to the combined string if the length is less than prescribed length?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, nsstring

In iOS I am using two strings to combine and to form a single string. But the combined string must be of 16 characters . So if two strings are small and if we combine both and if it is less than 16 characters I must add few more characters to make it to 16 characters. How to achieve this?

```
NSString *combined = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", stringURL, stringSearch];
```

This is the code I am using. So if I combine and it is less than 16 characters how to calculate it and add more characters to make it 16 characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like below

```
NSString *combined = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", stringURL, stringSearch];
if (combined.length < 16)
{
    NSString *newCombined = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", combined, @"Some new string"];
}
```

You can use  `substringWithRange`: method from `NSString`. You can take the below code as an example and modify it as per your requirements.

```
if (combined.length > 25)
{
    NSString *beginning = [combined substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 15)];
    NSString *fromEnd = [combined substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(startPoint, combined.length-startPoint)];
}
```

Comment: Maulik Thanks... I will try it and accept it if it works. But can you please help me how to remove the characters if the length of the string is more than 25 characters? For example if I have a string of 40 characters I must remove 15 characters(either from beginning or either from end) . how to achieve this?

Comment: @Fionashoff I have added some example code so at least you can start with it and modify it as per your requirements.

Comment: can you please tell me about EndPoint and start point? :)

Comment: Its an index number from where you want your string to be started and ended.

Comment: can you please post an example?

Comment: maulik I mean with working sample strings if possible :)

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of `stringWithFormat` - basically of `printf` if you want to pad with just a single char. Below I give some examples which I have constructed to illustrate, so it won't run out the box, but you only need to comment out the ones you do not want to make it work.

```
        // To get 50 spaces
        NSString * s50 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%*s", 50, ""];

        // Pad with these characters, select only 1

        // This will pad with spaces
        char * pad = "";

        // This will pad with minuses - you need enough to fill the whole field
        char * pad = "-------------------------------------------------------";

        // Some string
        NSString * s = @"Hi there";

        // Here back and front are just int's. They must be, but they can be calculated,

        // e.g. you could have this to pad to 50
        int back = 50 - s.length; if ( back < 0 ) back = 0;

        // Pad s at the back
        int back = 20;
        NSString * sBack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%*s", s, back, pad];

        // Pad s in front
        int front = 10;
        NSString * sFront = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%*s%@", front, pad, s];

        // Pad s both sides
        NSString * sBoth = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%*s%@%*s", front, pad, s, back, pad];
```

Note that the amounts here are parameterised. I use e.g. 50 in the first line but that could just as well be `n` as long as `n` is an int and you can use that to then perform calculations, store it in `n` and pad. There is an example in the code.

Here is a sample of the output

```
2020-11-04 08:16:22.908828+0200 FormatSpecifiers[768:15293] [Hi there-------------------------------------------------------]
2020-11-04 08:16:22.908931+0200 FormatSpecifiers[768:15293] [-------------------------------------------------------Hi there]
2020-11-04 08:16:22.908992+0200 FormatSpecifiers[768:15293] [-------------------------------------------------------Hi there-------------------------------------------------------]
```

I just show how to pad the combined string. To combine the string of course just use `stringByAppendingString` e.g.

```
NSString * s = [a stringByAppendingString:b];
```

and then you can do calcs based on `s.length` e.g. as shown in the example.